# Define const array definition

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I am using XE6 version of embarcadero and tried this:

```
 const
Elements = 2;
SUPPORTED_EXTENSIONS : array[1..Elements] of String = ('.jp2', '.j2k');
```

Error : Expected ';' found '='

And this:

```
Const
SUPPORTED_EXTENSIONS : TArray<String> = ['.jp2', '.j2k'];
```

Error : Type 'TArray' is not yet completely defined

How can i define this array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const
  Elements = 2;
  SUPPORTED_EXTENSIONS : array[1..Elements] of String = ('.jp2', '.j2k');
```

This code is correct and does compile. The compilation error you report is for a different piece of code, one that is not present in the question.

```
Const
  SUPPORTED_EXTENSIONS : TArray<String> = ['.jp2', '.j2k'];
```

Constant dynamic arrays are introduced in XE7. They are not available in XE6. So this code does not compile. The error message you report for the second code excerpt also does not match the code in the question. This code leads to this error:

> E2001 Ordinal type required

So, my main advice for you is to take more care in your work. Posting error messages that do not match the code you present suggests a degree of confusion. Go more slowly. Check and double check.

As an aside I would recommend that you prefer zero-based array indices. So I would write it like this:

```
const
  ElementCount = 2;
  SUPPORTED_EXTENSIONS: array [0 .. ElementCount-1] of String = ('.jp2', '.j2k');
```

Comment: I think, i make a stupid mistake but i could not find. Now this error is : formMain.SUPPORTED_EXTENSIONS does not has a corresponding component when i delete this part (= ('.jp2', '.j2k')). May be it helps you to find solution? I am new on delphi, sorry, if its stupid question

Comment: I think my answer already dealt with everything in your question. Now you are asking about some other code, code which I also cannot see. Given that neither of the errors you reported matched the code in the question, I am reluctant to attempt to address this comment. I have no real confidence that I understand what it asks. Perhaps you could be more precise.

Comment: okay i found my mistake, thank you my friend ;) "Check and double check." important :)